# Regex: add a dash (-) after digits

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to add a dash to a string, if there any characters after those digits, how would I do this with regex?

Examples:

```
dpa3455ad = dpa3455-ad

4545fd = 4545-fd
```

Comment: What do you mean by "character"?  A non-whitespace, non-digit? A letter?  Please specify exactly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. So you want to be able to add a dash at the end of all numbers in a string or after a particular set of numbers?

Comment: @Shirlz, Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: @Shimmy - I have added C# code in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex: ( asssuming you want to add a dash at the first point of occurence of a non-digit after a set of digits)

```
(\d+)(\D.*)$
```

and replace with `$1-$2`

C# code:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d+)(\D.*)$");
Console.WriteLine(re.Replace("dpa3455ad", "$1-$2"));
```

Will give - `dpa3455-ad`

To keep it simple and insert a `-` at every occurence of a a non-digit following a digit, use this:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d)(\D)");
Console.WriteLine(re.Replace("dpa3455ad1s", "$1-$2"));
```

Will give - `dpa3455-ad1-s`

Comment: Why are you using `+?` instead of just `+`?

Comment: @NullUserException - Good question, they will not have any difference in this situation

Comment: It *does* make a difference. This makes the engine backtrack unnecessarily.

Comment: @NullUserException - Agreed. I had given a different regex, the `?` was an artifact of that. Removed it now.

Comment: Hmmm, why is there a `.*` in there? Once you've found a non-digit it doesn't matter what comes next?

Seems a negative lookahead would be a simpler solution: `\d+(?!\d|$)` (replace with `$0-`)

Could also do `\d++(?!$)` if .net regex supports possessive quantifiers?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** slashes should be dollars for .Net.

Replace:

```
([0-9])([^0-9])
```

with:

```
$1-$2
```

The search string looks for a digit `[0-9]` followed by a non-digit `[^0-9]`, and records each as individual tokens `(...)`.  The replace string places a hyphen `-` between the two tokens `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: [According to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx), wouldn't it just be `Replace(/([0-9])([^0-9])/, /1-/2)`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, would you please show me the .NET code how to do it? I used the `Regex.Replace` function.

Comment: I'm talking about .NET, not JS, I this its' different.

Comment: Sorry, I had my slashes backwards.

Comment: Result: `dfm104\1-\2` or `dfm104/1-/2`

Comment: Okay, apparently those slashes need to be dollars.  I've never seen that in RegEx before.  Even the Microsoft IDE uses slashes.